# How do I make a certain area only accessible to me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In minecraft, I was planning to make a room only accessible to me, and I used this command:

```
/tp @e[r=20, type=!SnowyPanda] -414 71 599
```

Except the command didn't work and it kept on saying:

> Clarify which use you want to perform this command on

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that really the error message you get? If yes, your game is modded, because that error message does not exist in the regular game. It's not even grammatically correct.

Comment: Some identify as male, some identify as female, you apparently identify as a type…

Answer (score 3):

Is "SnowyPanda" your type? No, your type is "player". "SnowyPanda" is your name, so the command you want is:

```
/tp @e[distance=..20,name=!"SnowyPanda"] -414 71 599
```

Also make sure to not include spaces in the selector, it can break the command.

Since you only want to teleport players, you can also use `@a` instead of `@e`:

```
/tp @a[distance=..20,name=!"SnowyPanda"] -414 71 599
```

Comment: "you can use @a instead of @e" - *uses @p* ;)

Comment: no problem. we all make those small mistakes. :)